# Can I retract an edit suggestion under review?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

A new user posted a question without code formatting. I posted an edit suggestion which just applied code formatting - however while I was doing so, another (+2k) user made the same change and also formatted the error code. Now my edit looks like an attempt to mangle the error codes. Is there a mechanism to retract the edit suggestion before it gets rejected by the edit review queue?

This is the edit in question - I was literally twelve seconds behind @AChampion there! https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14558171

Comment: Thanks @Glorfindel - I was looking for 'retract' not 'undo' so didn't find that question.

Comment: You're welcome. The next person searching for 'retract suggested edit' will find this question, so thanks for creating a 'signpost'.